# Retrieving the information in the `change` dictionary from KVO

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing

The method

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
}
```

has a parameter `change` which is a dictionary that contains information about the nature of the value change, how would I find out what was in this dictionary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a list of the [keys used by the change dictionary](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Keys_used_by_the_change_dictionary).

An extract:

> #### Keys used by the change dictionary
>
> These constants are used as keys in the change dictionary passed to `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`.
>
> ```
> NSString *const NSKeyValueChangeKindKey;
> NSString *const NSKeyValueChangeNewKey;
> NSString *const NSKeyValueChangeOldKey;
> NSString *const NSKeyValueChangeIndexesKey;
> NSString *const NSKeyValueChangeNotificationIsPriorKey;
> ```

Comment: Also, remember to specify the NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew and/or NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld bitwise flags when setting up the observation.

Comment: How come each of them seem to mean more than one thing? And why do they make the descriptions so complicated?

Comment: Firstly, they look different to me. e.g `ChangeOld` is not the same as `ChangeNew` is not the same as `ChangeIndexes`. Secondly, they're complicated because they are specific. All the links to secondary documentation may look messy, but they reduce repetition.